# fatal: protocol 'https' is not supported

Tags: git, github, https, fatal-error

Getting this error whenever I'm running the command `git push -u origin master` after commits and adding the origin. How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Could you please paste your code instead of an image ? This will make it easier for people who will help you :-)

Comment: Show the output for `git remote -v`.

Comment: Have you checked out your project using SSH or HTTPS?

Answer (score 11):

Try removing the origin via

```
git remote remove origin
```

and adding the origin again via

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/YourUsername/YourRepo.git
```

It worked for me, when i encountered the exact same problem, since my orgin was corrupted.

Using gitbash, `git remote -v` didn't show anything unusual.
But using the Win10 cmd.exe `git remote -v` showed me an additional character just right before the `https://github.com/...`

I think this extra character might came along by copy-pasting the link from github into gitbash.

I didnt need to re-install git

Answer (score 1):

It could be that when you installed git on your local machine you didn't choose
 "Use the native windows secure channel library"

I had this issue too and after i removed git and installed with native windows library it worked

[image]

Comment: This answer worked for me, and resolved the same error which occurred during a call of ``git clone``.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the error message when trying to clone a repository. It did it on both HTTP and HTTPS addresses.

Just reinstalling Git on Windows 10 fixed the problem for me. I continued to use the OpenSSL library, which was the default option. I did not use the "native Windows Secure Channel library". I only changed 1 or 2 of the default options during installation, which should have been options having nothing to do with the problem we were experiencing. (One thing I did was have Git not change line-endings at all when committing/pushing. The default was to have it always change to UNIX line-endings when committing/pushing. I want complete control over this.)

After reinstalling, I tried cloning the same repository again, using HTTPS (github.com), and this time it worked fine. Quick and simple fix and uses less Windows stuff (i.e., no Windows Secure Channel library).